# Update key values in file of json, maintain file integrity, Python 3

Tags: python, json

I have file that has ~35k lines and I need to only change values for certain items in key base1, as below.  I need to change id and title values and save the same file.  Like, title becomes "title abc" and id becomes "789".

ex, before:

```
  "base1": {
    "base1base2": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "title": "title xyz",
        "visibility": true
      }
    ],
    "title": "title xyz"
  }
```

After some research and trial-n-error, this below worked-ish. I did similar to below (without the indent) but my file size was reduced in half when I expected very little, if any, change in file size.  Formatting was gone.  I saw someone suggested adding the indent portion as below, so I did that, but the file size went up a bit more than I expected and tons of spaces and \n were added.

```
wmjf = 'webmap.json'

with open(wmjf, "r") as jf:
   data = json.load(jf)
   data['base1']['base1base2'][0]['id'] = '789'
   data['baseMap']['baseMapLayers'][0]['title'] = 'title abc'
   data['baseMap']['title'] = 'title abc'
    
with open(wmjf, "w") as jf:
  json.dump(json.dumps(data, indent=4), jf)

jf.close()
```

Can I get some help on what I am doing wrong here with respect to maintaining the file as is, it's integrity, when doing these very minor value changes.  I wonder if the result of below is actually just fine for what I need (this reduces the size in half, no formatting, but I suspect it might work for republishing -- will try soon based on responses)

```
with open(wmjf, "w") as jf:
   json.dump(data, jf)
```

And, is this code good, correct, pythonic?  I am not a developer, just need to do small scripts here and there over the years, so I appreciate being set straight on my attempts, thx!  Also, I see some answers to similar questions with open mode r+ or w+ -- what does the + mean?

Comment: Your original file has 2 spaces of indentation for each level, so use `indent=2`

Comment: Why do you care about the formatting?

Comment: The 2 indent still adds lots of spaces and \n, but file size only reduced by a quarter.  And, indeed, maybe I don't need to care about formatting.  Will try later today.  This is webmap json that gets republished to the web, will try without the formatting and see if that works.

Comment: The original format you show at the top has spaces and newlines, what's the difference between that and `indent=2`.

Comment: After using the indent, the file looks like:   }\n      ]\n    }\n  ],\n  \"base1\": {\n    \"base1base2\": [\n      {\n        \"id\":

Comment: That looks similar to what you showed at the beginning of the question.

Comment: But the original question code and the original file do not have visible text of \n all over the file.  There are 'invisible' new lines, but not visible text of \n before vs after.  For after, I don't mean that there is nice formatting with new lines --- this is an exact copy and paste of after using indent=2 >> }\n ]\n }\n ],\n \"base1\": {\n \"base1base2\": [\n {\n \"id\":

Comment: Oh, now I understand. The problem is that you're calling both `json.dump` and `json.dumps`. Just do one or the other, not both. `json.dump(data, jf, indent=2)`

Comment: Yes, there we go!  Thanks!!  That looks much better.  I did copyNpaste that line from some answer somewhere in this forum.  Hmm.  Anyway, appreciate your help!!

Comment: You must have copied wrong. It was likely `jf.write(json.dumps(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call both `json.dump()` and `json.dumps()`. You're converting the data to JSON, then converting that JSON to another JSON string, so the newlines in the first JSON get converted to `\n` in the file.

Just call `json.dump()` and specify the indent there.

```
with open(wmjf, "w") as jf:
  json.dump(data, jf, indent=2)
```